# cakephp 2.x delete message show [object Object]

Tags: cakephp, message, delete-row

```
<?php echo $this->Form->postLink($this->Html->image("delete.png", array("alt"      => "Delete")), array('action' => 'delete', $personne['Personne']['id']),array('escape' => false) ,array('confirm' => __(' would you delete this personne # %s?', $personne['Personne']['id']))); ?>
```

when i click on delete image it show me [objet Objet] image :( i would have this  message " would you delete this personne"

[image: see this picture]

Answer (score 0):

postLink method's 4th argument is string|bool type.

Your code specified it array so you were shown [object Object].

```
<?php echo $this->Form->postLink($this->Html->image("delete.png", array("alt" => "Delete")), array('action' => 'delete', $personne['Personne']['id']),array('escape' => false) , __(' would you delete this personne # %s?', $personne['Personne']['id'])); ?>
```

Comment: what can i do? plz help me :(

Comment: delete array() from confirmMessage arguments.

<?php echo $this->Form->postLink($this->Html->image("delete.png", array("alt"      => "Delete")), array('action' => 'delete', $personne['Personne']['id']),array('escape' => false) , __(' would you delete this personne # %s?', $personne['Personne']['id'])); ?>